# Replace all values in pandas dataframe by lookup from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, replace

Given the following data:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(
        x1=["zero", "one", "two"],
        x2=["one", "zero", "zero"],
        x3=["zero", "two", "one"],
        x4=["zero", "two", "two"],
    )
)
```

which looks as:

```py
In [2]: df
Out[2]:
     x1    x2    x3    x4
0  zero   one  zero  zero
1   one  zero   two   two
2   two  zero   one   two
```

I would like to replace elements within it using the following:

```py
reps = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(
        val_from=["zero", "one", "two"],
        val_to=["nothing", "single", "couple"],
    )
)
```

resulting in the following data:

```py
    x1    : x2     : x3     : x4
  single  : single : single : single
   single : single : couple : couple
   couple : single : single : couple
```

The following works, but I feel there's a better approach:

```py
replacement = {x:y for x,y in zip(reps['val_from'], reps['val_to'])}
df.transform(lambda x: x.replace(replacement))
```

Comment: Is the `reps` DataFrame created like that in the actual program? Are the replacements values in another format?

Comment: @AMC this is just example data

Comment: Right, so how is the data actually stored/acquired?

Comment: @AMC irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) passing the `Series` with index "from" and values "to" from `reps`:

```
df.replace(reps.set_index(['val_from'])['val_to'])
```

[out]

```
        x1       x2       x3       x4
0  nothing   single  nothing  nothing
1   single  nothing   couple   couple
2   couple  nothing   single   couple
```

Comment: You don't really need `to_dict()`. Passing a series to `replace` works as well.